# Remote Desktop tool for ubuntu that can accommodate concurrent session with GPU acceleration

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

Is there any remote desktop tool out there for ubuntu/linux that allows multiple users to have concurrent sessions and allow GPU acceleration?